# To show all deleted files in Dropbox history

Tags: dropbox

**Problem**: Have a shared folder with 777 people where people randomly delete important items all the time.
You know never when it happens.
Solution for this should be designed.

**Challenge**: to list all pictures removed from Dropbox account during one year in the shared folder *MasiFolder*.

Settings

- Dropbox Pro
- Paid service: Permanent history of everything feature

where however no tools how to search effectively the history. 
The article [My files are missing. How do I get them back?](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/969) is insufficient where they can do unstably *How do I restore a single file?* 
However, you cannot list all files deleted in your account. 
Instead, they offer an open challenge about *Why did my files go missing?* without a systematic way to find out all files deleted:

> There are various reasons why files can go missing. Use this
>   troubleshooting guide to figure out what happened, and to get your
>   files back.

To find all deleted files would help significantly all files missing too.
Dropbox is concentrating to minimize the number of files missing, but not the show all deleted files. 
I think they should change the way about how they work.

### Insufficient search capabilities without searching at particular time interval and with option All pictures

Their find is insufficient with insufficient documentation in [How do I find a deleted or missing file in my Dropbox account?](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/970) and [How do I recover deleted files?](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/296) 
It misses most of the results:

[image]

where you can see no results with general empty search.
No possibility to search time interval.
Really useless search with these capabilities.
No possibility to search pictures.
No regex search. No guide, no will to improve their search, no help link there.

### Insufficient GUI to browse results about pictures

[image]

where you see awful view of resulted pictures; actually, they come but are too small.
Timeline view and other measures are wanted.
I want to see all pictures on my screen at once easily browse-able.
I see no other methods here for the solution.
I need to download all deleted items and manipulate the processing in my computer.

### About Dropbox's data structures

I think Dropbox team is struggling with their data structures in searching deleted items. 
I think they keep deleted items in different tables than the original files, making the search expensive. 
I cannot find any other explanation why they cannot answer my question.

**Dropbox's decision**: ignorant about their core problems: I forwarded this thread to their forum without answer, to their Twitter without answers and a couple of times to the Pro Support without answers.

---

How can you list, show and/or download all deleted items in Dropbox?

Comment: Seems like you should contact Dropbox support.

Comment: @Dan I did it already y sending this question to their twitter account. I also contacted them directly. I want them be open to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox added the feature of showing deleted files to the left-panel:

[image]

They say that the version history of deleted files is 1 year even if you have the paid-service of extended version history in Dropbox Pro. The Dropbox Business has unlimited version history.